# JAX-RS Webservice Architecture Patterns

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, jax-rs

What are the common practices for developing JAX-RS Webservices?

I think my architecture has kind of a smell to it:

The webservice is acting as a proxy, collecting information from different sources. There are RSS Feeds, SOAP Services and a Database.

I would like to abstract away the datasource in my business logic. Thats why I came up with something like this:

Persistence Layer:

```
| RSS Connector   Parser         SOAP Interface(s)             Entities        |
|     SomeRssDataDAO       SomeSoapDao   AnotherSoapDap    UserDao  ...Dao     |
```

Service Layer

```
|    SomeRssDataService            SoapDataService        UserFavoritesService |
```

"Resource" Layer

```
|       JerseyResources that map HTTP to service methods                       |
```

The service layer as well as the persistence layer would be EJBs.

The problem I'm facing is that I would have transactions in the persistence layer.
What if a services needs to use mutliple steps to do it's work, that wouldn't be right then.

But using transactions / the entitymanager in my service layer doesn't seem right to.

What's the way to go?

Also general Enterprise Application Architecture Tipps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with transactions being managed by the service layer. That's where the context to decide what should be atomic is and should be.

Your service layer doesn't need to be EJBs unless you plan to distribute them. You can use JDO or JPA transactions to manage persistence operations.

Your "Persistence Layer" doesn't really need to be EJBs either unless you plan to distribute them.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with this kind of structure. It evolved since then into a full fledged DDD application.